# how to set the start position of jquery UI draggable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm using jQuery UI and isotope, isotope does a bunch of things to the positioning of elements, and is messing up the start position of a dragged element.

When I start a drag, the element I am attempting to drag shows up in the top left of the parent, rather than underneath the cursor.

I've looked at the 'start' function, and I get the correct x,y coordinates from the event, but I can't seem to apply those values to the cloned draggable item.

My code looks like this

```
jQuery('div.item').draggable({
         helper: function(event, ui){
                 jQuery('div.hold_items').isotope('destroy');
                  var item_dragged = jQuery(this).clone().appendTo('body').css({'z-index':500,'top':event.clientY, 'left':event.clientX});
                 start_isotope();
                 return recipe_dragged;

         }
});
```

I have to do the start/stop isotope to resolve an issue where isotope is breaking the droppable function and items don't know where they are being dropped.

I'm sure there is a way to SET the draggable start-position, but I can't seem to find it in the documentation, just a way to get the start.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I am having a similar problem, with Isotope draggable seems to function funny. The start point of draggable element is way off.

Answer (score 1):

Posting my answer because I couldn't find the answer anywhere else- 
I had problems you are describing, and I solved it this way.. 
position the helper (it will try to get reset to 0,0)
Then we return false before it is reset to 0,0
It is canceled and at the correct position, but then we restart the drag by copying the event that was used to initiate the drag.

```
$(" #container").droppable({
drop: function (event, ui) {
    $(ui.draggable).detach().css({
        top: 0,
        left: 0
    }).appendTo(this);

}
});

$(" #draggable").draggable({
start: function (event, ui) {
    if ($(event.target).parent().is('.ui-droppable')) {
        var x = ($(this).offset().left);
        var y = ($(this).offset().top);
        var p = $(event.target).parent().parent();
        $(event.target).detach().insertAfter(p);
        $(ui.helper).css({
            'left': x - $(event.target).offset().left,
            'top': y - $(event.target).offset().top
        });
        var eventCopy = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
        eventCopy.initMouseEvent(event.type, event.bubbles, event.cancelable, event.view, event.detail,
        event.pageX || event.layerX, event.pageY || event.layerY, event.clientX, event.clientY, event.ctrlKey, event.altKey,
        event.shiftKey, event.metaKey, event.button, event.relatedTarget);
        ui.dispatchEvent(eventCopy);
        return false;
    }
}
});
```

Comment: actually.. I guess this doesn't work like I said it does. It just breaks the start event without returning anything. For some reason it still drags and has the correct position since it was set prior to ending the start event. If the event returns false, it would revert to the incorrect position, so you just need to call an exception for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

for jquery you can try using event.pageX and event.pageY as explained [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aMouse_Position).